How can I tell if SQL Server is RDS, RDS Custom, or installed manually on a VM (EC2)?
I only have direct access to the SQL Server. How can I check if it's RDS, RDS Custom (which allow to connect to the VM), or installed manually on a VM (EC2)?

Have you tried any of the ideas here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35915024/amazon-rds-sql-server-how-to-detect-if-it-is-rds or here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61658011/how-should-a-sql-script-detect-that-it-is-executing-on-an-aws-rds-sql-server-ins ?
